# Не запускается мейкфайл

Tags: c++, makefile

Выдает ошибку:

> C:\MinGW\cpp\Lab01>C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe Lab01
>   g++ -o Lab01.exe main.o -I.
>   main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x340): undefined reference to `sinusi(float, float, float)'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:11: recipe for target 'Lab01' failed
>   mingw32-make: *** [Lab01] Error 1

func.hpp:

```
#pragma once
float* sinusi(float,float,float);
```

func.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "fstream"
#include "func.hpp"
using namespace std;
float* sinusi(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float pivperimetr, ploshcha, sinA, sinB, sinC;
    if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a)
    {
        pivperimetr = (a + b + c) / 2;
        ploshcha = sqrt(pivperimetr*(pivperimetr - a)*(pivperimetr - b)*(pivperimetr - c));
        sinA = 2 * ploshcha / (c*b); 
        sinB = 2 * ploshcha / (c*a);
        sinC = 2 * ploshcha / (a*b);
        float* nnew = new float[3];
        nnew[0] = sinA;
        nnew[1] = sinB;
        nnew[2] = sinC;
        return nnew;
    }
    else
    {
        float* nnew = new float[3];
        nnew[0] = 0.0;
        nnew[1] = 0.0;
        nnew[2] = 0.0;
        return nnew;
    }
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I.

main.o:
    $(CC) -o main.o -c main.cpp $(CFLAGS)

func.o: func.cpp main.o
    $(CC) -c func.cpp $(CFLAGS)

Lab01: main.o
    $(CC) -o Lab01.exe main.o $(CFLAGS)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "fstream"
#include "func.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const float a = 5.8, b = 8.5, c = 6.8, d = 7.8, e = 5.1, f = 6.9;
    float arr1[] = { a,b,c,d,e,f };
    float arr2[6];
    ofstream out("text.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);
    for (int i = 0;i<6; i++)
        out.write((char*)&arr1[i], sizeof arr1[i]);
    out.close();
    ifstream in("text.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
    for (int i = 0; i<6;i++)
        in.read((char*)&arr2[i], sizeof arr2[i]);
    in.close();
    const int n = 3;
    float masiv[n][3] = { { a,b,e },{ b,f,d },{ a,c,d } };
    ofstream fout("rez.txt", ios::out);
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < n;j++) 
            fout << sinusi(masiv[i][0], masiv[i][1], masiv[i][2])[j] << " ";
        fout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make запустился, выполнил что прописано в Makefile и вернул ошибку линкера. А какой у вас собственно вопрос?

Comment: Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: В цели `Lab01` вы компонуете только `main.o`, забыв про второй файл. Надо так: *$(CC) -o Lab01.exe main.o **func.o** $(CFLAGS)*

Comment: А, всё, увидел. У вас `func.cpp` включается как заголовочный файл.

Comment: @Arhad чего бы вам не оформить в виде ответа?

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, он неверный. У вопрошающего хитрая схема зависимостей, на которую я поначалу не обратил внимания.

Comment: Вопрос только, зачем именно такая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас должны создаться 2 файла `rez.txt` и `text.txt`.

Попробуйте запустить в терминале `.\Lab01.exe`.

И в `main.cpp` `#include "func.cpp"` поменяйте на `#include "func.hpp"`.

Comment: `Попробуйте запустить` — нечего запускать, из-за ошибки компиляции exe-файл не создаётся. Подключение `*.hpp` вместо `*.cpp` тоже ничего не даст — `func.cpp` не компилируется напрямую, так как не описана соответствующая зависимость в `makefile`-е.